# SQLAlchemy select with where constraint

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a subset of a table from my database. The database is a MySql database.

Python code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, VARCHAR, DATETIME, INT, TEXT, TIMESTAMP
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
class TrackablesTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Trackables'

        trackableId = Column(INT, primary_key=True) #autogenerate
        productID = Column(TEXT)
        createdOn = Column(TIMESTAMP) #autogenerate
        urlTitle = Column(TEXT)
        humanTitle = Column(TEXT)
        userId = Column(VARCHAR(45))


        def __repr__(self):
                return "<MyTable(%s)>" % (self.asin)

        @staticmethod
        def getTrackableByProductId(productID, session):
            trackable = session.query(TrackablesTable).filter_by(productID=productID)
            return trackable
```

Note the method at the bottom. I was expecting this method to get me all the rows in the "Trackables" table with a "productID" column with the value of the productID variable. Instead, it seems to be returning a query which is malformed.

The query it returns is below:

```
SELECT "Trackables"."trackableId" AS "Trackables_trackableId", "Trackables"."productID" AS "Trackables_productID", "Trackables"."createdOn" AS "Trackables_createdOn", "Trackables"."urlTitle" AS "Trackables_urlTitle", "Trackables"."humanTitle" AS "Trackables_humanTitle", "Trackables"."userId" AS "Trackables_userId" 
FROM "Trackables" 
WHERE "Trackables"."productID" = :productID_1
```

MySQL workbench is telling me the query is malformed. Further, the value in the query of productID (":productID_1") is not the actual value of the variable referenced in the code.

Comment: The `:productID_1` is not a value, it's a placeholder that will be bound to a parameter passed to the `execute` function. This is how you avoid [Little Bobby Tables eating your database](http://xkcd.com/327/). If you turn up the debugging, you can see the value it passes to the `execute` and make sure it's the actual `productID` value.

Comment: Also, when you run your code, what actually happens? Does it raise an exception because it's a malformed query? Return the wrong results? Send threatening letters to Obama in your name?

Comment: @abarnert I don't get an exception in python. I only say it is malformed because if I take the query it reports and dump it wholesale into mysql workbench, then the workbench reports it is malformed. In python I get a Query object returned from the end of the code block. However, that object doesn't contain any information from the database.

Comment: Well, you can't take a query with parameters and execute it without parameters (which is what the mysql command-line tool, workbench, etc. will all do with it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to execute the query, not just return it.  The query remains a query object until a method such as `all()`, `first()`, or `scalar()` is called on it, or it is iterated over.

Your method should look like this:

```
@staticmethod
def getTrackableByProductId(productID, session):
    q = session.query(TrackableTable).filter_by(productID=productID)
    return q.first()
```

When you print out the query, SQLAlchemy shows the query with format placeholders rather than actual values.  The actual query is built by the dbapi (such as python-mysql) outside of SQLAlchemy's control.

---

*Side note: Your code, both the use of staticmethod and the naming conventions, looks like you've tried to copy a Java class.  Consider reading [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*